# how to write a query to show values in separate date columns

Tags: postgresql

I have some data

John has sum of money for the year =  30

Larry has sum of money for the year = 60.

Usually, the results in the database show like this...

| id | name | yearly sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 30 |
| 2 | larry | 60 |

so I want it broken down like this without personally inserting the values myself

| id | name | jan | feb | mar | apr | may |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 10 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | larry | 20 | 15 | 4 | 6 | 15 |

sample of the original data.

| Employee | company | contributions | months contributed on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Walmart | 10 | January |
| John | Walmart | 5 | Feb |
| John | Walmart | 4 | March |
| John | Walmart | 6 | Apr |
| John | Walmart | 5 | May |
| Larry | Amazon | 20 | January |
| Larry | Amazon | 15 | Feb |
| Larry | Amazon | 4 | March |
| Larry | Amazon | 6 | Apr |
| Larry | Amazon | 15 | May |

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as a pivot.  I'm not a PostrgreSQL expert, but this style of query is pretty easy to effect in virtually all SQL-compliant database management systems.

First, we'll create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE contributions
(
    Employee              varchar(50)
    , Company             varchar(50)
    , Contributions       int
    , Contribution_Month  varchar(10)
);
```

And insert some values into it:

```
INSERT INTO contributions (Employee, Company, Contributions, Contribution_Month)
VALUES 
     ('John',  'Walmart', 10, 'January')
   , ('John',  'Walmart', 5,  'February')
   , ('Larry', 'Amazon',  20, 'January')
   , ('Larry', 'Amazon',  15, 'February')
```

Here's the "pivot" bit:

```
SELECT
    totals.Employee
    , SUM(totals.January) AS January
    , SUM(totals.February) AS February
FROM (
    SELECT
        Employee
        , CASE WHEN Contribution_Month = 'January'  THEN Contributions ELSE 0 END  AS January
        , CASE WHEN Contribution_Month = 'February' THEN Contributions ELSE 0 END  AS February
    FROM contributions
    ) totals
GROUP BY totals.Employee;
```

And the results:

| employee | january | february |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 5 |
| Larry | 20 | 15 |

I've only included January and February since the other months would just be rote repetition, but you should be able to extend it to include the other months without much work.

PostgreSQL offers the [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) table function to produce a pivot table, which you construct like this:

```
SELECT 
    ct.Employee
    , ct.January
    , ct.February
FROM 
    crosstab
    (
        'SELECT Employee, Contribution_Month, Contributions FROM contributions'
    ) AS ct
        (
            employee varchar(50)
            , January int
            , February int
        );
```

The output looks exactly the same as my example above, so I'll not repeat it here.

[Here is a DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eb212554eddb96383aaacf0e11ad0ed2) for the above [minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve).